# Should I use null to see if a variable is empty in PHP?

Tags: php, performance

Which is better to use when I use _GET['something here'] for a variable to check if it is empty or not

```
if (isset($_GET['url']) != '') {
    //do stuff with it
}
```

OR

```
if (isset($_GET['url']) != NULL) {
    //do stuff with it
}
```

'' or null or something else?

Please don't call this over optimizing or micro optimizing, I am simply looking for best practices, thank you

Comment: Please note: `isset()` returns a bool, so it returns true or false, but never ever '' or NULL. So both your examples are wrong.

Comment: @frunsi if they both are wrong can you help make it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do the following to be sure that the value both exists and isn't empty

```
if(isset($_POST[myField]) && $_POST[myField] != "") {
Do my PHP code
}
```

Comment: That is what I used in the past but then I saw people doing it like if(isset($something)) and I ran it and it worked so I thought it was good, guess i should do the 2 checks

Answer (score 6):

Use empty() - it actually first test of the variable exists before testing whether something is in it.

[Edit: isset() returns only TRUE or FALSE, so both of the statements above work equally well]

Answer (score 2):

PHP can be a little painful when debugging blank/missing/empty value checks. You can use `empty()` or `isset()`, but remember the cases where `empty` returns true. It's highly liberal with what it considers [empty](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

```
Returns FALSE if var has a non-empty and non-zero value.

The following things are considered to be empty:

"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
```

`isset` is more conservative in that it only checks for variable's existence and a NULL value. From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL, FALSE otherwise.
```